# IE7 float bug. Is there a fix that maintains the html?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Here is a demo of my issue. This works correctly in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE7, the non-cleared floated elements end up at the top of the container next to eachother.
http://jsfiddle.net/eGAHx/

HTML:

```
<span class="bold floatLeft clearLeft">ISBN-13:&nbsp;</span>
<h2 class="floatLeft" itemprop="isbn">9780538735452</h2>
<span class="bold floatLeft clearLeft">ISBN:&nbsp;</span>
<h2 class="floatLeft">0538735457</h2>
<span class="bold floatLeft clearLeft">Edition:&nbsp;</span>
<span class="floatLeft" itemprop="bookEdition">3</span>
<span class="bold floatLeft clearLeft">Pub Date:&nbsp;</span>
<span class="floatLeft" itemprop="datePublished">2010</span>
<span class="bold floatLeft clearLeft">Publisher:&nbsp;</span>
<span class="floatLeft" itemprop="publisher">Brooks Cole</span>​
```

CSS:

```
.floatLeft{float:left}
.bold{font-weight:bold}
.clearLeft{clear:left}​
```

Expected outcome:
**ISBN-13:** 9780538735452
**ISBN:** 0538735457
**Edition:** 3
**Pub Date:** 2010
**Publisher:** Brooks Cole

Current IE7 outcome:
**ISBN-13:**  9780538735452053873545732010BrooksCole
**ISBN:

Edition:

Pub Date:

Publisher:**

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just use a UL with LABELS? http://jsfiddle.net/SqbgW/1/

Comment: That's an awful lot of markup. Any reason why you're using floats to achieve this? What's up with just a simple unordered list or even a definition list?

Comment: I think you are right. A UL would be the way to go here. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're floating these at all.

Why not just use `<strong>` tags for the text on the left, and `<br />` at the end of each line?

Comment: The original reason for the floats was due to the need of a few H2 elements. I guess I could make those h2s inline and use a <br/>. Either way, I would still like to find a fix for this when a similar situation arises where <br/> tags are inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for IE7 this style code in head tag

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <style type="text/css">
  h2{
    clear:both;
  }
 </style>
<![endif]-->
```

but you give parent h2 before h2 for example

```
yourparentelenent h2{
   clear:both
}
```